# Primefaces: Animation when rendered attribute changed

Tags: jsf, animation, primefaces, effect

Is there any possibility to add animation effect (show/hide) when the rendered attribute is changed?

For example:

```
<h:panelGrid rendered="#{myBean.show}">
    <p:effect event="show" animation="blend" />
    <p:effect event="hide" animation="blend" />
    ...
</h:panelGrid>
```

Best regards